# How to pass data using json array?

Tags: java, php, ajax, json, codeigniter

The data print like this array a object, object
I can't push that data into my table

> [{"brand_name":"EDNA","product_type":"Smacker","product_flavour":"Crispy","dealer_price":null,"price ":null,"open_stock":[{"openstock":"100.00"}],"total_purchase":[{"totalPurchase":null}],"free_issuese_in":[{"freeIssueseIn":null}],"stock_tra_in":[{"stocktrain":"100.00"}],"totalSales":[],"stockTraOut":[{"stout":"0.00"}],"freeIssuesOut":[{"SUM(stock_minus)":null}],"clossing_blnc":-100},{"brand_name":"EDNA","product_type":"Large","product_flavour":"Orange","dealer_price":null,"price
>   ":null,"open_stock":[{"openstock":"277.00"}],"total_purchase":[{"totalPurchase":"150.00"}],"free_issuese_in":[{"freeIssueseIn":"50.00"}],"stock_tra_in":[{"stocktrain":"3.00"}],"totalSales":[{"stock_plus":"0.00"},{"stock_plus":"0.00"},{"stock_plus":"0.00"},{"stock_plus":"0.00"}],"stockTraOut":[{"stout":"0.00"}],"freeIssuesOut":[{"SUM(stock_minus)":null}],"clossing_blnc":-277},{"brand_name":"EDNA","product_type":"Large","product_flavour":"Orange","dealer_price":null,"price
>   ":null,"open_stock":[{"openstock":"277.00"}],"total_purchase":[{"totalPurchase":"150.00"}],"free_issuese_in":[{"freeIssueseIn":"50.00"}],"stock_tra_in":[{"stocktrain":"3.00"}],"totalSales":[{"stock_plus":"0.00"},{"stock_plus":"0.00"},{"stock_plus":"0.00"},{"stock_plus":"0.00"}],"stockTraOut":[{"stout":"0.00"}],"freeIssuesOut":[{"SUM(stock_minus)":null}],"clossing_blnc":-277},{"brand_name":"EDNA","product_type":"Large","product_flavour":"Orange","dealer_price":null,"price
>   ":null,"open_stock":[{"openstock":"277.00"}],"total_purchase":[{"totalPurchase":"150.00"}],"free_issuese_in":[{"freeIssueseIn":"50.00"}],"stock_tra_in":[{"stocktrain":"3.00"}],"totalSales":[{"stock_plus":"0.00"},{"stock_plus":"0.00"},{"stock_plus":"0.00"},{"stock_plus":"0.00"}],"stockTraOut":[{"stout":"0.00"}],"freeIssuesOut":[{"SUM(stock_minus)":null}],"clossing_blnc":-277},

[image: Blockquote]

this picture show how data pass into the table. if i print array it show correct data.

but the data showing like this

my javascript i pass data using json

```
   success: function (data){
      alert(data);
      var order = JSON.parse(data);
      var order_detail = [];
        $j('#lbl_rescount').text.length;
        $j('#rows_token').val.length;
     // var or_de =[];
      if (order!== 0) {
      for( var x=0; x<order.length;x++){
          order_detail.push(
                  '<tr>'

       +'<td>'+ order[x].brand_name + '</td>'
       +'<td>'+ order[x].product_type + '</td>'
       +'<td>'+ order[x].product_flavour +'</td>'
       +'<td>' + order[x].dealer_price +'</td>'
       +'<td>' + order[x].price +'</td>'
       +'<td>' + order[x].open_stock +'</td>'
       +'<td>' + order[x].total_purchase+'</td>'
       +'<td>'+ order[x].free_issuese_in + '</td>'
       +'<td>'+ order[x].free_issuese_in + '</td>'
       +'<td>' + order[x].tot +'</td>'
       +'<td>' + order[x].total_sales +'</td>' 
       +'<td>'+ order[x].stock_tra_out + '</td>'
       +'<td>'+ order[x].free_issues_out + '</td>'
       +'<td>'+ order[x].clossing_blnc + '</td>'
       +'</tr>'
               );
```

model i get data

```
    $sql="SELECT
        tu.user_id,
        tt.territory_id,
        tp.product_id,
        tpt.product_type,
        tb.brand_name,
        product_flavour
        FROM
tbl_product tp
    INNER JOIN
tbl_product_type tpt ON tpt.product_type_id = tp.product_type_id
    INNER JOIN
tbl_category tc ON tc.id_category = tp.category_id
    INNER JOIN
tbl_brand tb ON tb.id_brand = tc.brand_id
    INNER JOIN
tbl_product_flavour tpf ON tpf.product_flavour_id = tp.flavour_Id
    INNER JOIN
tbl_stock_history_manage tshm ON tshm.product_id = tp.product_id
      INNER JOIN
tbl_territory tt ON tt.territory_id = tshm.territory_id
        INNER JOIN
tbl_user tu ON tu.user_id = tshm.user_id
  where
 tshm.status = 1  



";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            foreach ($query->result() as $row){
                $sql2="SELECT
                        SUM(`dealer_price`) AS dealer_price
                        FROM 
                        `tbl_product_has_price` 
                        WHERE `product_id` = $row->product_id
                      ";//price(rd)

                    $query2= $this->db->query($sql2);
                    $dealer_price =$query2->result();

                $sql3="SELECT sum(price) as price 
                       from
                       tbl_purchase_order_has_details
                      WHERE
                       product_id = $row->product_id 

                        ";  //price(pur)      

                    $query3 = $this->db->query($sql3);
                    $price =$query3->result();

                $sql4="SELECT
                         SUM(`stock_plus`) as totalPurchase
                        FROM 
                          `tbl_stock_history_manage`
                        WHERE 
                          `stock_type` = 'PURCHASE'
                        AND  
                       product_id = $row->product_id 
                        AND territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id"; //total purchase       

                    $query4 = $this->db->query($sql4);
                    $toatal_purchase =$query4->result();    

                     $sql5="SELECT 
                             SUM(`stock_plus`) AS freeIssueseIn
                            FROM 
                              `tbl_stock_history_manage`
                    WHERE 
                     `stock_type` = 'PURCHASE_FREE' 
                    AND  
                       product_id = $row->product_id 
                             AND territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id"; //free issuse in      

                    $query5= $this->db->query($sql5);
                    $free_issuese_in =$query5->result(); 


                    $sql6="SELECT
                        SUM(`stock_plus`+`mobile_stock_plus`) AS stocktrain 
                    FROM 
                      `tbl_stock_history_manage`
                    WHERE 
                         `stock_type` = 'STOCK ADJESMENT PLUSE'
                     AND
                       product_id = $row->product_id 
                            AND territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id"; //stock_tra_in      

                    $query6= $this->db->query($sql6);
                    $stock_tra_in =$query6->result(); 

                      $sql7="SELECT
                           SUM(`stock_plus`-`stock_minus`)+sum(`mobile_stock_plus`-`mobile_stock_minus`) AS openstock
                        FROM 
                             `tbl_stock_history_manage` WHERE

                       product_id = $row->product_id 
                         AND territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id "; //open stock      

                    $query7= $this->db->query($sql7);
                    $openStock =$query7->result();


                    $sql8="SELECT
                        `stock_plus`
                    FROM
                      `tbl_stock_history_manage` 
                    WHERE
                        `stock_type` = 'SALES'
                         AND
                       product_id = $row->product_id 
                          AND territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id"; //totalSales      

                    $query8 = $this->db->query($sql8);
                  $totalSales =$query8->result();

                    $sql9="SELECT
                SUM(`stock_minus`+`mobile_stock_minus`) AS stout 
                FROM 
               `tbl_stock_history_manage`
                WHERE
               `stock_type` = 'STOCK ADJESMENT PLUSE' AND
                       product_id = $row->product_id  AND
                             territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id"; //stockTraOut     

                    $query9= $this->db->query($sql9);
                  $stockTraOut =$query9->result();

                   $sql10="SELECT
                    SUM(stock_minus) 
                FROM 
                 `tbl_stock_history_manage` 
                WHERE 
                 `stock_type` = 'FREE' 
                 AND
                       product_id = $row->product_id  AND territory_id = $row->territory_id
                         AND user_id = $row->user_id"; //freeIssueseOut     

                    $query10= $this->db->query($sql10);
                  $freeIssuesOut =$query10->result();
                    $return_array[] = array(
                                            'brand_name'=>$row->brand_name,
                                            'product_type'=>$row->product_type,
                                            'product_flavour'=>$row->product_flavour,
                                            'dealer_price'=>$dealer_price->dealer_price,
                                            'price '=>$price->price ,
                                            'open_stock'=>$openStock,
                                            'total_purchase'=>$toatal_purchase,
                                            'free_issuese_in'=>$free_issuese_in,   
                                            'stock_tra_in'=>$stock_tra_in,
                                          //'tot'=> number_format(count($open_stock) > 0 ? $open_stock[0]->openstock:0,2)+($total_purchase[0])+($free_issuese_in[0])+($stock_tra_in[0]->stock),//total
                                            'totalSales'=>$totalSales,
                                            'stockTraOut'=>$stockTraOut,
                                            'freeIssuesOut'=>$freeIssuesOut,
                                            'clossing_blnc'=>  number_format(count($stockTraOut)> 0 ? $stockTraOut[0]->stout :0,2)+( $freeIssuesOut[0]->stock_minus)+($totalSales[0]->totsales)-number_format(count($openStock) > 0 ? $openStock[0]->openstock :0,2)+($toatal_purchase[0]->stock_plus)//closing balance
                                            );


            }
            return $return_array;
```

actually i don't know what is the solution for my question  . if that java script can pass the data for loop inside forloop or .? please if any one help me print correct data in to the table...

Comment: Read this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking but if your problem is that you want values for each items then pay attention that output from JSON.parse to your JSON code will not be simple one dimensional array. So for example if you want to access in loop to value called openstock, then you can do it something like that:

```
for( var x=0; x<order.length;x++){
...        
    +'<td>'+ order[x].open_stock[0].openstock +'</td>'
}
```